# How to generate the assembly code from C file by GCC

Tags: assembly, gcc, makefile

I follow the GCC syntax to generate the **assembly code** using GCC and makefile on Windows environment, but I cannot find the .s file generated. Could you please suggest what is wrong with the below makefile? Thanks a lot.

```
CFILES = $(wildcard *.c)
OFILES = $(CFILES:.c=.o)
GCCFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles
GCCPATH = C:\gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-mingw-w64-i686-aarch64-none-elf\bin

all: clean kernel8.img

# %.S: %.c
#   $(GCCPATH)\aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -S $< -o $@

kernel.S: kernel.c
    $(GCCPATH)\aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -S -o kernel.S kernel.c

boot.o: boot.S
    $(GCCPATH)\aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c boot.S -o boot.o

%.o: %.c
    $(GCCPATH)\aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

kernel8.img: boot.o $(OFILES)
    $(GCCPATH)\aarch64-none-elf-ld -nostdlib boot.o $(OFILES) -T link.ld -o kernel8.elf
    $(GCCPATH)\aarch64-none-elf-objcopy -O binary kernel8.elf kernel8.img

clean:
    rm kernel8.elf *.o *.img
```

Comment: What target are you invoking? `make all` will not generate kernel.S, as it's not needed by anything. `make kernel.S` should work.

Comment: This is targeted for ARM Cortex A72. Yes it works. Thanks a lot @dratenik

Comment: By "target", dratenik meant `make` target, not platform. His suggestion was to explicitly provide the target, `kernel.S` since your `all` target did not include generating the `.S` fiile and you probably just typed `make`.

Comment: Thanks, @lurker, main target is .img file, however, I also need to generate kernel.S to check.

Comment: You can either specify the targets explicitly (`make kernel.S kernel8.img`) or change your first target in the makefile (which is the default target, in this case, `all`) to be what you want, `all: clean kernel8.img kernel.S`. Btw, including `clean` as part of your `all` is a little unusual. Typically, `clean` is kept as a separate target to avoid unintentionally cleaning files.

Comment: Got it. The clean action there is to make sure there is a clean environment before building the firmware. Thanks a lot for your suggestion @lurker